# Mongodb feature compatibility version

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-replica-set

I want to add new servers to my replica set.
So I used `rs.add("<IP>:<PORT>")` to add the servers.
But the servers became not reachable. On checking Logs I found out it was feature compatibility version issue. So I updated the feature Compatibility Version using,
`db.adminCommand({ setFeatureCompatibilityVersion: "3.6" })`.
But on checking status I got,

```
rspp1:PRIMARY> db.adminCommand( { getParameter: 1, featureCompatibilityVersion: 1 } )
{
        "featureCompatibilityVersion" : {
                "version" : "3.4",
                "targetVersion" : "3.6"
        },
        "ok" : 1,
        "$gleStats" : {
                "lastOpTime" : {
                        "ts" : Timestamp(1681888293, 1),
                        "t" : NumberLong(27)
                },
                "electionId" : ObjectId("7fffffff000000000000001b")
        },
        "$configServerState" : {
                "opTime" : {
                        "ts" : Timestamp(1681889207, 1),
                        "t" : NumberLong(5)
                }
        }
}
```

.
This means for some reason my upgrade is stuck and not finished.
I need a way to revert it back to `3.4`.
Also `db.adminCommand({ setFeatureCompatibilityVersion: "3.4" })` doesn’t work because the first upgrade is not completed yet.
I want ot stop the update and revert it back to 3.4
Kindly help me.

I tried `db.adminCommand({ setFeatureCompatibilityVersion: "3.6" })`.
I was expecting `{ "ok": 1 }`

Comment: How did you update? Did you follow [Upgrade a Replica Set to 3.6](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/release-notes/3.6-upgrade-replica-set/)? Just a note, the same page also provides [Downgrade 3.6 Replica Set to 3.4](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/release-notes/3.6-downgrade-replica-set/)

Comment: I can't downgrade it because the previous upgrade is stuck. It's not completed yet. how can I complete or kill it?

Comment: Again, did you follow the procedure. An upgrade may take several hours (without causing any problem) And what do you mean by "I found out it was feature compatibility version issue"? What is the error message?

Comment: The error looke like, "2023-04-14T10:06:19.718+0200 F STORAGE [initandlisten] Unable to start up mongod due to missing featureCompatibilityVersion document." this error was found in the logs file of the server that I added in the replica set. I did follow the procedure nad it's been 4 days. I don't know what's wrong with this.

Comment: What is the actual version of the `mongod` binaries? Did you mix any?

Comment: I'm not aware of how can I see that. But the server version is 3.6.23 and Feature compatibility version was 3.4 and then I upgraded it to 3.6 which is where it's stuck.

Comment: Use `mongod --verison` to get it.